# How to change listview items?

Tags: java, android, http, listview, http-get

I'm getting strings from a HttpGet and I want to place them into the listview. How could I do this? I can't find any information on it anywhere. At the movement, I just have some test data in place.

Eg.

"Test1"

But I want it to be dynamic, from the strings the phone get's from the HttpGet.

Thanks.

My Code so far: (Apologies for the code being messy, I'll rewrite it soon!)

```
public class ChatService extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chatservice);
        try {
            ContactsandIm();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CheckLogin();


        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        list.setClickable(true);

        final List<PhoneBook> listOfPhonebook = new ArrayList<PhoneBook>();
        listOfPhonebook.add(new PhoneBook("a", "9981728", "test@test.com"));
        listOfPhonebook
                .add(new PhoneBook("Test1", "1234455", "test1@test.com"));
        listOfPhonebook.add(new PhoneBook("Test2", "00000", "test2@test.com"));

        PhonebookAdapter adapter = new PhonebookAdapter(this, listOfPhonebook);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long index) {
                System.out.println("sadsfsf");
                showToast(listOfPhonebook.get(position).getName());
            }
        });

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void CheckLogin() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://gta5news.com/login.php");

                try {

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    Log.w("HttpPost", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent())
                            .toString();
                    Log.w("HttpPost", str);

                    if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                        Log.w("HttpPost", "TRUE");
                        try {Thread.sleep(250);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //put intent here(21/3/12); 

                    } else {
                        Log.w("HttpPost", "FALSE");

                    }

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
                String line = "";
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                // Read response until the end
                try {
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        total.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Return full string
                return total;
            }




    private void ContactsandIm() throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;


        HttpClient get = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI website = new URI("http://www.gta5news.com/test.php");
        HttpGet webget = new HttpGet();
        webget.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = get.execute(webget);
        Log.w("HttpPost", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        //now we'll return the data that the PHP set from the MySQL Database.



        // just some test code, to see if the HttpGet was working.
        if (in.equals("True")); {
            Toast.makeText(this,"yay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }






    }

    // end bracket for "ContactsandIm"

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's that? I've never seen this method before.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, i see that PhonebookAdapter is your custom adapter class. Why not parse the http response of type PhoneBook and add it to listOfPhonebook. That should show the parsed contents in the listView.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to add new PhoneBook entry every time your Http request is succeeded.
If so, you have to options to make everything dynamic:

1. Recreate adapter every time you receive new portion of data:

   - Make your listView global variable (to make it accessible from any function within the class)
   - Do the same with your List
   - Once you have received new portion of data - add this data to your List, create new adapter and set this adapter to your ListView
2. Create a custom adapter with possibility to update ListItems:

   ```
   public class YourCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
   {
       private final LayoutInflater inflater;
       private ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
       private Handler uiHandler = new Handler();


   /*..... default set of functions from BaseAdapter ......*/

   public void setList(ArrayList<PhoneBook> list)
   {
       this.list = list;
   }

   public void addEntry(final PhoneBook entry)
   {
       uiHandler.post(new Runnable()
       {
           @Override
           public void run() 
           {
               list.add(entry);
               YourCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
       });
   }


   }
   ```

   - please note that in this case you are allowed to modify underlying list ONLY from UI thread

Hope this helps